# Best way to provision vSphere VMs remotely

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, script, automation, api

**Edit**: Sorry, should have mentioned this upfront: looking for a Linux-only solution here.

I'm looking for a way to automate the process of provisioning vSphere VMs remotely. I'm wondering what is typically done or considered a "best practice" here:

- Does vSphere expose a REST API for this sort of thing?
- Does vSphere expose a CLI that I could SSH into from a remote server and issues commands inside of?

Ideally, Process A living on Machine 1 could reach out to a vSphere server living on Machine 2, tell it to provision, say, 20 VMs using a particular template, and then vSphere acknowledges when the VMs are provisioned and online. Ideas?

Comment: [PowerCLI](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/) should do the trick. I didn't post as an answer as I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks @NathanC (+1) - however please see my edit. I should have mentioned this upfront: I need to be able to do all this scripting/automation from a Linux machine, and I *believe* (of course, correct me if I'm wrong) PowerCLI is Windows-only. Ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Something like [Puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/cloudprovisioner_vmware.html), perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSphere api:
https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc%2Fright-pane.html

There are plenty of implementations, one of them being PYSphere in python: https://code.google.com/p/pysphere/

or Java:

http://vijava.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks @Raf (+1) - what about Java clients?